# Yet another boring FizzBuzz

Tags: java, beginner, fizzbuzz

I've just finished my first program written in Java. It's a simple, boring, yet well-known FizzBuzz challenge where you have to:

> Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for
>   multiples of three print “Fizz” instead of the number and for the
>   multiples of five print “Buzz”. For numbers which are multiples of
>   both three and five print “FizzBuzz”."

I know there are some other FizzBuzz questions here, but I'd really like to start learning Java in the right way, which means that I'm looking for:

- Naming conventions
- Coding standards and best practices

Coming from Python world, I was tempted to create a separate method named `fizzBuzz()` which I then called in my `main()` method. Is this a bit overkill for such a simple task?

```
package fizzbuzz;

class FizzBuzz {
/*
    Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of
    three print “Fizz” instead of the number and for the multiples of five print
    “Buzz”. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print
    “FizzBuzz”."
 */

    public static void fizzBuzz() {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
                System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
            else if (i % 3 == 0)
                System.out.println("Fizz");
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
                System.out.println("Buzz");
            else
                System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fizzBuzz();
    }
}
```

Comment: I always try to get out of the main method and file as fast as possible. To me, that place should only be used to launch the app and nothing else. So yes, creating a separate method or class is the right approach.

Comment: An enterprise version of FizzBuzz in Java can be found here: https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition

Comment: If your FizzBuzz isn't boring, you did it wrong.

Comment: You could shorten the `if..else` if you use a `String` variable and concatenate using ternary: `String strOut = ""; strOut = ((i % 3) ? "Fizz" : "") + ((i % 5) ? "Buzz" : ""); System.out.println((strOut.length() > 0) ? strOut : i)`. I'm not sure how this stands up to everyone's scrutiny, but it reads cleaner to me than an `if..else`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Coming from Python world, I was tempted to create a separate method named `fizzBuzz()` which I then called in my `main()` method. Is this a bit of overkill for such a simple task ?

Well, it is a little bit too much for such a simple task, but it is a good habit to do so and if I were you I would stick to it.

---

Overall your `fizzBuzz` looks good.

- Naming -> Check

but

- Best Practices -> Fail

This is because you omitted braces `{}` although they are optional for single instruction `if`, `else if` and `else` branches.

Omitting the braces can lead to hidden, and therefore hard to find bugs. I would like to encourage you to always use them.

Another thing is that you have some magic numbers, like `1`, `100`, `3`, and `5` in your code which should either be extracted to some meaningful named constants, or passed to the method as parameters.

You **could** add a `isDivisibleBy(int value, int divider)` method as well to make the responsibilities clear.

Comment: While 1 and 100 can be passed as parameters, the use of 3 and 5 are specific to this algorithm, and I wouldn't expect them to be extracted, since it's obvious what they're doing.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez this just depends wether you want to extend its usability for  e.g `2` and `3` printing `Bizz`, `Fuzz` and `BizzFuzz`. Its just a hint that it **could** be extended.

Comment: I have to echo @ArturoTorresSánchez's point. Extracting a FizzDivisor and a BuzzDivisor is like creating a function `isEven(x, evenDivisor = 2)`.

Comment: The “best practice” bit is by no means generally agreed on. For what it’s worth I disagree that always using braces is best practice, and there’s no evidence that it actually prevents bugs. On the flip side, it takes up more vertical space, thus pushing functions over the height of the monitor, which may make code harder to read and, in turn, may lead to bugs. In other words, it’s far from clear which leads to more robust code: always using braces, or omitting optional braces.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It only adds one line per if/else chain when this bracing style is used.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser Which means a 33% increase in code size for individual `if` statements. If you for instance have lots of guards at a method start this can be a hefty penalty.

Comment: I have to disagree with the `isDivisibleBy` function idea, it's unnecessarily verbose, and adds extra complexity. The modulo operation is much clearer. Checking for divisibility is a really basic/common task in programming, and any decent programmer would understand what you're doing there. "Keep It Simple, Stupid"

Comment: @Jezzamon even if you have 200 places in your code where you can used `isDivisibleBy`... would you still recommend not using it?

Comment: @Honey unless we expect the definition of `isDivisibleBy` to change or `isDivisibleBy` has edge cases we want to handle cleanly and consistently (ala String.isNullOrEmpty), I would not use it. I would support creating a variable to hold the 3 and 5 because those might change and finding/updating 200 instances would be error-prone, but the core concept of `% == 0` shouldn't change.

Answer (score 27):

Congratulations.

First, because you made it quite easily into the next round of your job interview. That's better than 80% to 90% of all candidates applying for the average software development job apparently. Seriously, a lot of people applying for jobs wouldn't have been able to write that code.

Second, because you resisted the temptation to write an "enterprisy" solution. No builder. No factory. No factory builder, no factory builder factory, just the simple, straightforward solution to a simple, straightforward problem. Giving a solution that requires >50 lines of code, even if bug free, would mean you turned an easy victory into a crushing defeat.

It's a design pattern called "YAGNI" = You Ain't Gonna Need It. You will never, ever in your life need to run this code in any other way, with other numbers than 3, 5 and 100, or with any other words than "Fizz", "Buzz" and "FizzBuzz". Therefore you should not write code that does more than solve the problem.

Comment: I'm confused... your answer is saying that the OP's code is great and there is nothing to change? Shouldn't this be a comment then?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice I think from a *You Ain't Gonna Need It* perspective he means this is a great answer + a nice poking at his interview :D

Comment: @Honey I get that, but I think "you're code is fine and not overly complex" explained in 150 words still doesn't make an answer. It's really a comment.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice "Your code is fine as it is", stated with justification, [is a perfectly acceptable answer on Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/96/9357). It would not be appropriate as a comment, though.

Comment: @200_success Thanks for the link, I didn't know that :)

Comment: From an interview perspective, ive often read to ask regarding design constraints and goals when given a challenge; in this case, after asking, suppose ive been told they want an easily extensible or modifiable solution. Should i engineer a little harder?

Comment: "better than 80% to 90% of all candidates applying for the average software development job ". Seriously? I worry that I won't be able to get a SD job (currently in tech support) because although I know Assembler, Java, Swift, REXX, Perl, Python, Bash script and Objective-C , I'm not a superstar in any of them.

Answer (score 7):

**Use proper parentheses**

> ```java
> if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
> ```

Contains 6 operations in a short line. While one can somewhat easy see what you intend (since we know the code's intention) you will have an awesome bug at hand if you make a mistake when assuming operator precedence.

**Improvement 1: Place parentheses**

```java
if ( ((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0) )
```

Now precedence is none of your worries any more, but of course if your condition becomes more complex, it will look increasingly terrible. Also note that you use the expressions

`(i % 3) == 0` and `(i % 5) == 0`

multiple times. Why calculate them twice in the worst case?

**Improvement 2: Extract expressions**

```java
boolean numberFizzes = ((i % 3) == 0);
boolean numberBuzzes = ((i % 5) == 0);

if(numberFizzes && numberBuzzes){
…
} else if(numberFizzes){
…
} else if(numberBuzzes){
…
} else {
…
}
```

**Improvement 3: Reorder cases to reduce complexity**

Why cover the *FizzBuzz* case first, if it is

- the most complex
- composed from two other cases

A simple re-ordering and breaking up the *if-else* cascade helps you cover the corner case quite nice:

```java
boolean numberFizzes = ((i % 3) == 0);
boolean numberBuzzes = ((i % 5) == 0);

if(numberFizzes){
    // print Fizz
}

if(numberBuzzes){
    // print Buzz
}
// In the FizzBuzz case both will now be printed

if( !(numberFizzes || numberBuzzes) ){
    // print i
}
```

While in the concrete example the gain is arguably small, the lesson is that problem can be re-constructed to come to other solutions that may have beneficial impact on your code smell.

Comment: Disagree that `if ( ((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0) )` is "proper parenthesis".   If I saw that on a interview I'd wonder if the candidate didn't understand precedence or order of operations, and what other trivial things they might not know.

Comment: Good point about extracting the expressions, but I think `numberFizzes` is a misleading variable name; I'd expect a variable with that name to hold a number value, not a Boolean. I'd lean instead toward something like `isMultipleOfThree`.

Comment: @Nick: Interesting, never thought about it this way. I prefer explicit parenthesis (and/or the _one action at a time_ paradigm) to make very clear what I intend. Consequence is of course that you stop thinking about precedence, since it becomes irrelevant. I would consider this more a piece of defensive programming, than actual lack of knowledge. However now you got me interested: which other pieces of knowledge would one probably lack if one can't get the precedence right?

Comment: @Thriggle: Point taken, maybe it may also be called `numberIsFizzing` or something. If _to fizz_ would be a verb, `numberFizzes` could be interpreted as `numberDoesFizz` (what I meant), or `numberOfFizzes` (what you read).

Comment: I agree with Nick, I expect everyone to know all the "standard" precedence rules (though some operators, are more obscure: except in high-performance code, I would expect comments for bitwise/bitshift ops). Those 3-var operations are dead simple. **I reserve omittable parenthesis to sub-results that bear a meaning in themselves** (like conforming to a math equation). Regardless of your own habit, the candidate *will* encounter expressions with omitted parenthesis, if they are baffled by it they are not yet of an adequate skill level, and I might wonder if they ever will be.

Comment: Am I taking crazy pills? This is like, five times harder to read, to me.

Comment: re: improvement 2: That isn't a number of Fizz or Buzz, it's a flag. If you are going to go down this path then naming should be `hasFizz` and `hasbuzz`

Comment: This is less clear than the OPs attempt.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: can you elaborate please? Is there something specific that catches your eye? As far as the discussion goes, it seems obvious that I use a style which one half of the people approves and the other one disproves. I am curious to learn what leads to the latter.

Answer (score 6):

This escalated quickly. And wow, I've never been called enterprisy before, I'm proud. So, anyway, I'm obviously not recommending anyone to do FizzBuzz like this: I mean, it's obviously an overkill, and a horrible first solution to turn in when asked at an interview. I used the basic problem as a springboard to show OP some concepts (magic constants, encapsulation, builder pattern) and also some language features (constructor delegation, Javadoc) they may not be familiar with. Also, as an interviewer I'd bloody well ask follow-up questions like "but I like my FizzBuzz parametrizable" and "what's wrong with this constructor?", and I'd prefer to get answers like this.

---

And in addition to the answers posted by @Heslacher and @TimothyTruckle: I would take this even further.

Because, really, what are those magic numbers doing in the code? 3, 5 and 100, all code checkers ([checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) or [PMD](https://pmd.github.io)) would complain about these. Sure, we could extract them into static constants:

```
private static final int FIZZ_NUMBER = 3
private static final int BUZZ_NUMBER = 5
private static final int ITERATIONS = 100
```

But I like my FizzBuzz configurable: the user of our FizzBuzz lib should be able to specify these constants. Likewise, just printing stuff on the console is bad form in any language: why can't I supply my own outputstream?

The obvious solution is to encapsulate the FizzBuzz logic into its own class:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    private final int fizzNumber;
    private final int buzzNumber;
    private final int iterations;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param fizzNumber We should print a "fizz" when the current 
     *                   iteration is divisible by this number
     * @param buzzNumber We should print a "buzz" when the current 
     *                   iteration is divisible by this number
     * @param iterations The simulation should run this many cycles.
     */
    public FizzBuzz(int fizzNumber, int buzzNumber, int iterations) {
        this.fizzNumber = fizzNumber;
        this.buzzNumber = buzzNumber;
        this.iterations = iterations;
    }

    /**
     *  Constructor creating a vanilla FizzBuzz, with parameters 3, 5, and 100
     */
    public FizzBuzz() {
        this(3, 5, 100);
    }

    /**
     *  Write fizzes and buzzes on the given output stream.
     *
     *  @param out The outputStream we should write fizzes and buzzes on.
     */
    public void write(OutputStream out) {
         // fizzbuzz logic
    }

    /**
     *  Write fizzes and buzzes on the standard output.
     */
    public void write() {
        this.write(System.out);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
FizzBuzz writer = new FizzBuzz(5, 2, 200);
writer.write();
```

---

That constructor, though... 5 and 2, which was the Fizz and which was the Buzz? Writing constructors with a relatively large numbers of indistinguishable paramters harms the readability of the code. I'm really fond of [the builder pattern of Joshua Bloch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/477453):

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    private FizzBuzz(int fizzNumber, int buzzNumber, int iterations) {
        this.fizzNumber = fizzNumber;
        this.buzzNumber = buzzNumber;
        this.iterations = iterations;
    }

    /* FizzBuzz implementation here. */

    public Builder create() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public static final class Builder {
        private int fizzNumber = 3;
        private int buzzNumber = 5;
        private int iterations = 100;

        private Builder() {
            // private ctor to hide the default one.
        }

        public Builder withFizzNumberOf(int fizzNumber) {
            this.fizzNumber = fizzNumber;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withBuzzNumberOf(int buzzNumber) {
            this.buzzNumber = buzzNumber;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withIterations(int iterations) {
            this.iterations = iterations;
            return this;
        }

        public FizzBuzz done() {
            // perform checks on the parameters here.
            return new FizzBuzz(fizzNumber, buzzNumber, iterations);
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
FizzBuzz fizzBuzz = FizzBuzz.create()
    .withFizzNumber(7)
    .withBuzzNumber(3)
    .withIterations(200)
    .done();
```

---

Oh and, use Javadoc to document your code!

Comment: This is what I would call 'over-engineering' :) Don't get me wrong, it is a *perfectly valid solution* if you think your requirements will change. But if you know they won't, don't bother making everything parameterized.

Comment: @RobAu sure, I got carried away a bit here :). OP asked for idiomatic Java, though, and this is pretty idiomatic Java. Also, everybody seems to put this in the context of an interview: while this is most definitlely a really bad solution to give at first, as an interviewer I'd ask questions like this.

Comment: I *love* that this answer puts "fizzbuzz logic" as an implementation detail to be filled in later.

Comment: If you're going to complain about magic numbers, isn't it best that they be provided by a properties file at runtime instead of hard coded in the source code?

Comment: @Andonaeus As I see it, this FizzBuzz is a parametrizable library. Plugging in the actual values, coming from properties files or user input or whatever is the responsibility of the caller.

Comment: @SáT that makes sense, I added my comment for completeness, really. Part of the requirement in the question is actually invoking the code, so we should be aware of these magic numbers and how best to handle them on invocation as well.

Comment: So... This isn't satire...?

Comment: @Agop No, sorry. It wouldn't be too subtle to be satire anyway.

Comment: If you are going to do this the builder should have steps like; `addRule(3,"Buzz")`

Answer (score 6):

## Overkill?

I wouldn't say it is overkill. As Ben C. R. Leggiero says:

> I always try to get out of the main method and file as fast as possible. To me, that place should only be used to launch the app and nothing else. So yes, creating a separate method or class is the right approach.

Plus, I can now call `FizzBuzz.fizzBuzz()` from one of my classes. (Although, on the other hand, I guess one could ask why I would ever need to use your `fizzBuzz()` function.) I wouldn't do more than though. In this case, it's 2 lines of code more for some re-use and re-enforcement of a good practice... Remember FizzBuzz is usually an interview question... A lot of abstraction is just not going to be needed. There aren't very many use cases for this problem.

## Javadocs

You can document your code with [Javadocs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html). The code you have right now doesn't utilize this, and it is pretty trivial to fix your existing comments to do this.

## Use braces

This is the most important issue. This:

```
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
            System.out.println("Fizz");
        else if (i % 5 == 0)
            System.out.println("Buzz");
        else
            System.out.println(i);
```

Is prone to errors when you don't use braces. Python enforces indentation so it is hard(er?) to make a mistake with the lack of braces, but in Java the indentation doesn't influence anything here and some programs will silently "work" that shouldn't and no error message will be given.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer of @Heslacher which I totally support:

> Coming from Python world, I was tempted to create a separate method named fizzBuzz() which I then called in my main() method. Is this a bit of overkill for such a simple task ?

You should have gone one step further.

Java is an *object oriented language* therefore you are encuraged to (create and) use *objects*. There are two little changes in your example to do so:

```
public /* remove static */ void fizzBuzz() {
  // ...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FizzBuzz().fizzBuzz();
}
```

---

Another point I'd like to stress is *visibility scopes*.

Your method `fizzBuzz()` has `public` visibility which means it can be accessed from anywhere throughout your program. You should always reduce the visibility as much as possible. Since there is no other class (yet ;o)) needing access to this merhod you should replace the `public` key word by `private`.

---

**[edit]**
The comments to my answer raised another issue:

*identifier names should express programmers intention*

You named your method `fizzBuzz()` which is a repetition of the classes name.

But method names should start with a verb.

Therefore the method should better be called `execute()`, `run()` or alike.

Comment: You never know when you would need any FizzBuzz

Comment: Is it me, or is it missing a FizzBuzzServiceProviderFactoryProviderFactory?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt There are lots of non oo programming languages out there. If you dislike objects stay away from Java.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: Nothing against objects. Mostly C# / C++ here. I just think it overkill to make a FizzBuzz class (and would frown at the solution if it were presented to me (had it been in my repertoire for interviewing candidates to begin with)). To each their own :)

Comment: Out of 4 fizzbuzzes, surely only one can be used instead of polluting code with way to much use of the same word.  
public /* remove static */ void doWork() {
  // ...
public static void whatEver() {
    new FizzBuzz().run();
}

Comment: Oh and in case you have only ever known "Java", Python is an object oriented language so you can and are encouraged to use "objects"

Comment: @ReubenMallaby *"Out of 4 fizzbuzzes, surely only one can be used"* I corrected the copy/paste error in my answer, but somehow I think your point was something else... ;o)

Comment: Thanks @TimothyTruckle, I just don't see the point in repeating the same name multiple times - a name for the class and a name for the action.

Comment: @ReubenMallaby: You're right, the method should have been named something like `execute` or `run`, but that was the TO's example and I didn't want to change it that much.

Comment: FizzBuzz constructor should really accept parameters: the magic numbers should be changable, and I'd like to supply my own outputsream too, if possible. I'd be even tempted to make a builder for this.

Comment: @SáT do you like to add your own answer or do you expect me to add that to my answer?

Comment: Hmmm, I'll give it a try :).

Comment: Surely @SáT is being sarcastic. This answer is over-engineered. Just because Java is an OO language doesn't mean that a simple function like fizzBuzz() should be turned into a class. Or should we start doing `sum = new AddOperation(5, 3).execute()`?

Comment: @SáT: Look up YAGNI.

Comment: @Agop *"Just because Java is an OO language doesn't mean that a simple function [...] should be turned into a class"* You cannot program in Java without a class. You *could* program in Java by not creating objects, but as I wrote earlier: why then using Java (or any other OO language)?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I'm not implying you should avoid objects in Java. All I'm saying is that for this particular program, there is absolutely no reason to use anything other than a static method. In fact, I wouldn't even advise using a separate method for this.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: The object (no pun intended) of Java is not turning everything into a class.  Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. Not creating a class out of every spec of dust does not imply you're using Java wrongly (or any object oriented language for that matter) , it's just an indication that you've given thought to what should be modeled and what not.

Comment: @gnasher729 YAGNI is perfectly fine for designing systems and writing real world applications. YAGNI is not applicable when you're learning a language. YAGNI can also be abused as saying "too much trouble". YAGNI also implies a heavy refactor phase when the requirements do change. Also, YAGNI is a rule of thumb to prevent wasting too much time designing something that won't be used. If it's not too much time (extracting shit to classes is not too much time), then it's a case of whythehellnot.

Comment: @SáT In the case of FizzBuzz, the "why not" is because it *doesn't accurately model what you're doing*. This is not complex data you have to process or a long procedure with significant state you have to manage. FizzBuzz is a simple procedural algorithm, and it's best modeled by a simple list of statements with a loop thrown in. Anything else actively detracts from the readability.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'd tend to agree if FizzBuzz was actually an algorithm. It isn't. It's a model of an algorithm, a placeholder, a tool to demonstrate concepts and ideas. But even if it was a proper algorithm, I'd contend it needs to be extracted into a method, or a class proper. Consider Bresenham's algorithm, that's not much more complex than FizzBuzz: would you really just stuff it in the main? Would you really extract it into a function only if it's used more than once?

Comment: @SáT It's not a question of how many times it's used. It's a question of whether there's any intuitive way to break up the logic. There isn't with FizzBuzz. What are you going to split out of it? The printing and give the function a lambda? That isn't an improvement; by definition FizzBuzz won't be output to anything else. By comparison, the output of Bresenham's algorithm is unlikely to stand alone; it has to modify an existing raster. That means you need other code to generate a blank raster or load whatever input one you want to use. So you have natural boundaries to divide the logic.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to consider this:

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
   String output = "";
   if (i % 3 == 0) {
     output += "Fizz";
   }
   if (i % 5 == 0) {
     output += "Buzz";
   }
   if (output.length() == 0) {
     output =  Integer.toString(i);
   }
   System.out.println(output);
}
```

This

- reduces the number of print calls which makes it easier to redirect later if required.
- combines the "Fizz" and "Buzz" for "FizzBuzz" which makes it easier to add a check for future divisors (typical followup question on an interview)

Comment: I don't like `output = "Fizz";`. That's a bug waiting to happen if we want to add something for numbers divisible by 2.

Comment: @jpmc26 - I agree. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I have some feedbacK:

DRY (don't repeat yourself): you have repeated both `i % 3 == 0` and `i % 5 == 0` twice.

[Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): your code is doing (at least) two things: 1) mapping rules to words, and 2) printing the words. If there was a requirement to print the words in some other way, you'd need to change about 50% of the entire code (I'm also thining [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) here); ideally you'd be able to implement a new type of 'printer' and inject in as a dependency.

I would expect to see some test code e.g. given 3 input then 'fizz' output, given 7 then '7' output, etc.

Comment: There is DRY code and there is code golf. In this case I think both solutions are fine.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is fine, but IMO FizzBuzz is a bad example to have a discussion of conventions and best practices about. The "problem" has only one purpose: to make an interview candidate demonstrate that they can actually write a logically correct piece of functioning code. Will it compile? Will it work? Will it fit on the sheet of paper we gave the candidate? That's all that matters for FizzBuzz. It demonstrates a most basic proficiency that is barely higher than HelloWorld. It's not the best direction to pursue for actually learning a language.

Comment: Sanity is good.

Answer (score 3):

You ask if moving fizzbuzz outside of main is overkill, I would say yes and no.  No, because main should not be doing complex logic, it should be short and simple.  If there is complexity, that should be handled elsewhere.  Yes, because you moved the WRONG THING out of main.

Fizzbuzz has three components, a loop to be executed some numbers of times, a calculation on a given value, and printing the result of said calculation.  You move all three of these out of main into another function, but you don't actually gain anything by doing so.

Turn the calculation into a function that returns a result.  At that point, you will probably want to have the loop stay in main, but either way, it will be a better program.

```java
public static String fizzBuzzTransformation(int numToTransform) {
   if (numToTransform % 3 == 0 && numToTransform % 5 == 0)
      return "FizzBuzz";

   if (numToTransform % 3 == 0)
      return "Fizz";

   if (numToTransform % 5 == 0)
      return "Buzz";
                
   return numToTransform.toString();
}
```

Stylistic comments.  You have a class, it has a public static main method and a public static method fizzBuzz. They do exactly the same thing.  After moving the calculation out into it's own method, I would eliminate the fizzBuzz method, at that point it's just a loop and a println, well within what I would consider acceptable for main to be doing, and just as importantly, acceptable for another class to do if it wants to take advantage of your class. Main is as "pure" as it needs to be, it exercises the capability of the class in a simple straightforward manner.

Comment: The code is not indented properly.